# Forth program in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, forth

I have a complex program, written in Forth, that runs under DOS. I use [DOSBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox) to run this under Windows 7.

Is there a way to somehow get this program running on the cloud, so that I might access it, with full I/O, from any Internet-enabled computer?

Comment: Accessable on the internet isn't really "in the cloud" per-se. In the cloud simply refers to a program existing on a cloud of computers - large data centers where it would be running on no one defined computer, for example, on [heroku](http://heroku.com)

Comment: need more info on the I/O requirements. you can do simple stdin/stdout via xinetd on a Linux cloud instance, but I'm not sure which emulator (bochs, qemu, wine, etc) will work for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no need to have a cloud based solution.

There are a number of **FORTH** interpreter implementations in Javascript. For example [JSFORTH](http://forthfreak.net/jsforth.html).

You can easily create a webpage including a FORTH javascript interpreter and your FORTH code that you will be able to access from everywhere.
This solution, however, will only be able to provide text I/O, from your question it is not clear if your application requires other I/O types.

Depending on your security requirements, I would also recommend to use some userid/password authentication to protect this website.

Answer (score 1):

The more-expensive, less-work option: pay for a VPS or dedicated server, run qemu on it to run your Forth program in its original environment.

The less-expensive, more-work option: port your Forth program to run under gForth or SwiftForth in a Linux environment, and pay for shared hosting.